# Biblatex: a question about the bibliography style for my thesis, specific bibliography format

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex, natbib, bibliographystyle

I am currently working on my PhD thesis and have problems in bibliography style. I want to have a style as:

1. Geerlings, P., F. De Proft and W. Langenaeker, “Conceptual Density Functional Theory”,
   *Chemical Reviews*, Vol. 103, No. 5, pp. 1793–1874, 2003.

author names should be like:

Surname, Initial of the first name.

First letters of the words in article title should be capitalized

journal name should be without abbreviation and should be in italics